# assign value to indexes in drop down list in java

Tags: java, swing

I am a java begginer and making a GUI program that contains a drop down list of months like

```
JComboBox month;
public static String[] monthname = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
month = new JComboBox(monthname);
```

I have added it in to frame and it's working properly.
I want to assign numeric values against each index of month name array. I just want to implement if user selects month April, how to assign value 4 against April.

Comment: I want to assign values dynamically by using loops. but don't know how to use loop here. I've never used loops in GUI

Comment: Don't need to make loops..

Comment: then how to aassign dynamic values...? Static values assigning will be time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `Map` and assign key values to the months. The ideal would be having the int as key, but since you want the integer value of the month, make this:

```
Map<String, Int> months = new Hashmap <String, Int>();

months.put("january", 1);
months.put("february", 2);
...
```

So, this way:

```
months.get("january");
```

Will return `1`.

As your key is a String and January could be also `january`, or `JANUARY`, you should convert all Strings you are getting into `Lowercase`. That's why I put them in lowercase on the **map's key field**.

Comment: Thanks Asier. Map is a new thing for me but I'm happy I've learned something new. Gonna try this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I edited the declaration of the Map, since I first put the key as the Int and the Value as String (check it, that was my fault).

Comment: Asier just clear me one thing. Map is used inside the constructor or outside...?

Comment: mmm I don't know what you mean. Constructor of the class? Give me more info so I could explain to you

Comment: hehehe yes I was confused on that point you are using Int first and using it on later. Thanks for clearing. I've checked

Comment: I'm making a program that will return day from date. Currently I'm making its GUI. I'm sending you complete code of my GUI. Please instruct where i should use Map

Comment: we shall continue there ; )

Comment: bro, I don't have 20 reputations to chat with you :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32062/discussion-between-azeem-khalid-and-asier-aranbarri)

Answer (score 1):

Try `month.getSelectedIndex() + 1`

Comment: Thanks. I think it's the easier solution

Comment: As it is 1 line :D However for more complex mapping situations @AsierAranbarri's response is more apt...